# Hazelcast map-store approach with Spring Data - JPA silently failing

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hazelcast

I am trying to implement a zero-boilerplate map-store for a hazelcast based cache (as described [here](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.6/manual/multi_html/ch14s05.html)), but I cannot get any data saved to my database when I add them to my map.

This is how I define the hazelcast map:

```
<hz:map name="foo"
  <hz:map-store enabled="true"
                class-name="my.package.jpa.UserDataRepository"
                write-delay-seconds="1"/>
</hz:map>
...
<bean id="cacheManager" class="com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager">
  <constructor-arg ref="user-provisioning-hazelcast"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userMappingCache" factory-bean="cacheManager" factory-method="getCache">
  <constructor-arg><value>foo</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The map seems to be working (in memory, at least).

This how I define the CRUD interface at my.package.jpa.UserDataRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserDataRepository extends JpaRepository<UserData, Long>,
      JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserData> {}
```

When I use the `save` method of the bean that gets created from that interface definition, on any of my objects, data gets saved to the database (so the database connection, hibernate properties, Entity definition and bean definitions seem to be ok).

But when I "put" objects into the map, hazelcast never writes them to database and it never complains. The map-store definition seems to be ignored.

The key is the same with id of the JPA object.

Any clue of what could be wrong or how to debug will be appreciated.

Using hazelcast 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

hz:map configuration should be under hz:config. Also you should declare map outside.

Is it, can you check that?

Comment: Both of those things are fine.  I think that the problem is that since I declare the CRUD repository as an interface, hazelcast cannot instantiate it (so I should find a way to make hazelcast connect to the implementation of that interface that Spring/JPA instantiates).  I don't know how to do that...